# HTTP 403 Forbidden - Auth JASS Spring Camel

Tags: java, spring, ldap, jetty, jaas

I have the following configuration to connect to an active directory with username/password to authenticate a REST DSL service in Camel. http://localhost:3000/api/data/1234

```
<!-- Jetty Security handling -->
<bean id="loginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
    <property name="name" value="nameAuth"/>
    <property name="loginModuleName" value="ldap-login-module"/>
</bean>

<bean id="identityService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultIdentityService"/>

<bean id="constraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC"/>
    <property name="roles" value="Admin" />
    <property name="authenticate" value="true"/>

</bean>

<bean id="constraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="constraint"/>
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/*"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
    <property name="authenticator">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="constraintMappings">
        <list>
            <ref bean="constraintMapping"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="loginService" ref="loginService"/>
    <property name="identityService" ref="identityService"/>
</bean>
```

When sending correct credentials it returns 403:

```
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /api/data/1234. Reason:
        <pre>    Forbidden</pre>
    </p>
    <hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
    <hr />

</body>
```

When changing them and sending wrong credentials returns 401

```
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /api/data/1234. Reason:
        <pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
    </p>
    <hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
    <hr />
</body>
```

Can it be caused by the role or something?

I appreciate if you know of any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using netty4 and not jetty.

https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/netty4-http-component.html

```
restConfiguration()
            //.component("jetty")
            .component("netty4-http")
            //.endpointProperty("handlers", "#securityHandler")
            .endpointProperty("securityConfiguration.realm", "ldap-login-module")
```